# Frameworks, design patterns, and libraries for building an HTML5/javascript tablet app

Tags: javascript, html, tablet

I would like to build an HTML5/javascript news reader for tablets. I know HTML, javascript, and CSS pretty well, and I am a proficient programmer in Python and Java. I understand generally how I would go about building this app, but I want to know if there are any frameworks, design patterns, or libraries in general that I should take advantage of to avoid doing everything from scratch.

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Browser compliance:**

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), DOM library of choice, [ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim),  etc. Will deal with making sure you it just works across devices and browsers.

**Overall structure:**

You may want to structure your codebase, either roll out your own micro framework or use existing ones like [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/), [agility](http://agilityjs.com/), [spine](http://maccman.github.com/spine/), [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/)

**Micro libraries:**

Need some specific functionality? Go to [microjs](http://microjs.com/) and check your not re-inventing the wheel. Or check [NPM](http://npmjs.org/) for whether it already exists.

**Server side things:**

There's the general unit testing frameworks, source control, server side frameworks, build environments, packagers, minifiers, etc. That you need to take care of.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there's a mobile version of jQuery. Not sure what the feature differences are besides some optimizations for touch-based interface, but jQ is pretty well-established and future developers are likely to be familiar with it.